# Are classes necessary for creating methods (defs) in Python?

Tags: python

Are classes necessary for creating methods (defs) in Python?

Answer (score 12):

No. However, `def`'s which aren't part of a class are usually called functions, not methods - but they are exactly the same thing, aside from not being associated with a class.

```
def myFunction(arg1, arg2):
    # do something here
```

Comment: You might argue they're not *exactly* the same, as static, class and instance methods behave differently as far as if and what is passed as the implied first argument.

Comment: Nathan, I disagree.  An unbound class method is simply a function.  Only a *bound* class method has an implied first argument. Even then, it's just a function with a first argument curried into it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can create functions using `def` without having to wrap them in classes.

If you are coming from a Java or C# background - where a class is required - you may want to read over [An Introduction to Python: Functions](http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/functions/) or a similar article to understand how to work with functions in Python, as the language provides many other features such as first-class functions, returning multiple values, anonymous functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "method".

In some sense, no, classes aren't necessary for creating methods in Python, because there *are no methods* anyway in Python. There are only *procedures* (which, for some strange reason, are called *functions* in Python). You can create a procedure anywhere you like. A *method* is just syntactic sugar for a procedure assigned to an attribute.

In another sense, yes, classes *are* necessary for creating methods. It follows pretty much from the definition of what a method is in Python: a procedure stuck into a class's `__dict__`. (Note, however, that this means that you do not have to be inside a class *definition* to create method, you can create a procedure anywhere and any way you like and stick it into the class afterwards.)

[Note: I have simplified a bit when it comes to exactly what a method is, how they are synthesized, how they are represented and how you can create your own.]

Comment: Oh, I can supply the “strange” reason: they're called “functions” in C too. Like functions in C and in Pascal, Python functions always have a return value. There are no Pascal-style “procedures” in Python. Now, what exactly is the meaning you assign to “functions” and “procedures”?

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: There are many equivalent ways to define what a function is. Roughly speaking, a function consists of a triple `(D, C, F)` of sets, where `D` is the domain of the function, `C` is the codomain, and `F` is a set of pairs `(a, b)`, such that `∀(a, b): a ∈ D ∧ b ∈ C ∧ every e ∈ C is the first element in exactly one pair`. Python's procedures violate the last condition, therefore they aren't functions. A procedure is basically the same as above, except that the last condition doesn't need to hold and it can have side-effects. (Those two conditions are actually the same.)

Comment: Python is not math (and you should know that), neither are several other programming languages happily calling subroutines as “functions”. If I may veer off, brake pads have a totally different function in cars which no-one calls strange, and you should function rather differently in stackoverflow.com than in mathoverflow.net. Finally: practicality beats purity :)